# ChunkWM suggests cding into directory that does not exist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Tags: install, macports

When trying to install chunkwm, with MacPorts, I'm getting an instruction to,

> 2. Symlink prepared agent and start it:
>
>    ```
>    cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
>    ln -s /opt/local/Library/LaunchAgents/com.koekeishiya.chunkwm.plist
>    launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.koekeishiya.chunkwm.plist
>    ```

However, I don't have a `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. What do I do? **I know I can create the directory with `mkdir`**, but  I have no idea what that directory structure entails. My LaunchAgents in it `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`. The last time I put something in `~/` (Xcode) I found out much later that it needed to be in `/Applications` instead (and that it wasn't "installed" unless it was in /`Applications`. I'm wondering if this path was for an older version of MacOS?

Also, can I just `launchctl` from

```
launchctl load -w /opt/local/Library/LaunchAgents/com.koekeishiya.chunkwm.plist
```

Why does it want this to be in the home directory?

I checked in [the MacPorts FAQ](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ), and this isn't mentioned.

Comment: `mkdir ~/Library/LaunchAgents` works miracles in such cases...

Comment: In general: If you run into installation issues, check out the FAQ/support site of the product first. If this doesn't help, and there is no obvious way to contact/ask for support there, post a question here, add a link to the instructions you've followed and explain what you already tried to solve the problem. Otherwise it's just a lot of guess-work on our side, often for problems which are already known and solved.

Comment: @nohillside I know how to create the directory, I'm wondering if that's what I'm supposed to do. I have no idea what that directory structure entails. My LaunchAgents in it `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`. The last time I put something in `~/` (Xcode) I found out much later that it needed to be in `/Applications` instead (and that it wasn't "installed" unless it was in `/Applications`

Comment: Why do we have to contact support on a third party site before we ask questions about OSX Software and Hardware? Isn't that *exactly* what this site is for? I did check the FAQ. If you want me to leave, I can take the questions to SuperUser. But, I would like to help seed your community with well formed questions for OSX and MacPorts since I'm brand new to both.

Comment: @nohillside see if that clears up the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man launchd`:

```
FILES
 ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
 /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the adminis-
                                trator.
 /Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the admin-
                                istrator.
 /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS X.
```

So user-specific agents should be in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. If the directory doesn't exist it can be created with `mkdir ~/Library/LaunchAgents`.